# VBA Excel: Invalid Property

Tags: excel, vba

I get the error "Invalid property" for `.Caption =`. Any ideas why? TabData is my userform name and HiddenLabel is my label name. RList() is an array that I am trying to index to find the largest element. Thanks for the help!

```
 For l = 1 To R_win
        Set TabData.HiddenLabel.Caption = RList(l).Value
        w = HiddenLabel.Width
        If w > m Then
            m = w
        End If
    Next l
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `Rlist()` is an array then use:

```
TabData.HiddenLabel.Caption = Cstr(RList(l)) '<-- CStr() function converts the array content into a string
```

otherwise tell us what `Rlist()` is...

Answer (score 0):

You don't `Set` the Caption property. It's a string, not an object.  You need to do this:

```
Dim obj As Variant
Set obj = TabData.HiddenLabel
obj.Caption = RList(l).Value
```

Or just omit the `Set` keyword and use:

```
TabData.HiddenLabel.Caption = RList(l).Value
```

Comment: Sorry, declare obj as `Variant`. I updated the answer.

Comment: afaik Variant is not an object so you won't need to to use Set as an addition

Comment: I now get 'Object required' for Obj.Caption = RList(l).Value

Comment: Sounds like you need to review the basics of [Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251642.aspx). Or just omit the `Set` keyword per my second example.

Comment: Omitting 'Set' just gets me another error: 'Object required.' Thanks for trying though.